# Is it pythonic to import inside functions?

Tags: python, conventions

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says:

> - Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module
>     comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

On occation, I violate PEP 8. Some times I import stuff inside functions. As a general rule, I do this if there is an import that is only used within a single function.

Any opinions?

**EDIT (the reason I feel importing in functions can be a good idea):**

Main reason: It can make the code clearer.

- When looking at the code of a function I might ask myself: "What is function/class xxx?" (xxx being used inside the function). If I have all my imports at the top of the module, I have to go look there to determine what xxx is. This is more of an issue when using `from m import xxx`. Seeing `m.xxx` in the function probably tells me more. Depending on what `m` is: Is it a well-known top-level module/package (`import m`)? Or is it a sub-module/package (`from a.b.c import m`)?
- In some cases having that extra information ("What is xxx?") close to where xxx is used can make the function easier to understand.

Comment: and you do that for performance?

Comment: I feel it makes the code clearer in some cases. I would guess raw performance drops when importing in a function (since the import statement will execute every time the function is called).

Comment: You can answer "What is function/class xxx?" by using the import xyz syntax rather than the from xyz import abc syntax

Comment: If clarity is the only factor, U could as well include a relevant comment, to that effect. ;)

Comment: @becomingGuru: Sure, but comments can get out of sync with reality...

Comment: @codeape: so why comment code at all, right? Now I know why comments are rarer and rarer...  ;-)

Comment: Related question: [In python, what happens when you import inside of a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3095071/12892).

Comment: I do not feel it pythonic... However:

Using Azure functions, it seems like variables defined in the Application Settings or local_settings.json are not available until the main function is called, so whatever module (settings) that tries to use them must be imported within.

Another case when the rule might be violated.

Comment: I have the same question but for an entirely different reason. Say I want to make different functions for importing and curating different large datasets. Importing them all at once at the top of the file would cause many unnecessary imports and take a long time to load, since perhaps only one dataset is desired to be used. In this instance, what's wrong with importing within the function that is called for that particular dataset?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should import statements always be at the top of a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module)

Comment: `https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#loaders`: "If the module is a Python module...the loader should execute the module’s code in the module's global name space..."

Comment: I did not see a conclusive answer. The biggest question is why importing (at the top) a model that might not be used? In my case I am using a nested `if-elif` to select one of several models.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

In the long run I think you'll appreciate having most of your imports at the top of the file, that way you can tell at a glance how complicated your module is by what it needs to import.

If I'm adding new code to an existing file I'll usually do the import where it's needed and then if the code stays I'll make things more permanent by moving the import line to the top of the file.

One other point, I prefer to get an `ImportError` exception before any code is run — as a sanity check, so that's another reason to import at the top.

You can use a linter to check for unused modules.

Comment: Thanks for the ImportError tip, I had never thought of that one!

Answer (score 58):

There are two occasions where I violate PEP 8 in this regard:

- Circular imports: module A imports module B, but something in module B needs module A (though this is often a sign that I need to refactor the modules to eliminate the circular dependency)
- Inserting a pdb breakpoint: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` This is handy b/c I don't want to put `import pdb` at the top of every module I might want to debug, and it easy to remember to remove the import when I remove the breakpoint.

Outside of these two cases, it's a good idea to put everything at the top.  It makes the dependencies clearer.

Comment: I agree it makes dependencies clearer with regards to the module as a whole. But I believe that it can make the code less clear at the function level to import everything at the top. When you're looking at a the code of a function you might ask yourself: "What is function/class xxx?" (xxx is used inside the function). And you have to look at the very top of the file to see where xxx comes from. This is more of an issue when using from m import xxx. Seeing m.xxx tells you more - at least if there is no doubt as to what m is.

Answer (score 24):

Here are the four import use cases that we use

1. `import` (and `from x import y` and `import x as y`) at the top
2. Choices for Import.  At the top.

   ```
   import settings
   if setting.something:
       import this as foo
   else:
       import that as foo
   ```
3. Conditional Import.  Used with JSON, XML libraries and the like.  At the top.

   ```
   try:
       import this as foo
   except ImportError:
       import that as foo
   ```
4. Dynamic Import.  So far, we only have one example of this.

   ```
   import settings
   module_stuff = {}
   module= __import__( settings.some_module, module_stuff )
   x = module_stuff['x']
   ```

   Note that this dynamic import doesn't bring in code, but brings in complex
   data structures written in Python.  It's kind of like a pickled piece of data
   except we pickled it by hand.

   This is also, more-or-less, at the top of a module

---

Here's what we do to make the code clearer:

- Keep the modules short.
- If I have all my imports at the top of the module, I have to go look there to determine what a name is.  If the module is short, that's easy to do.
- In some cases having that extra information close to where a name is used can make the function easier to understand.  If the module is short, that's easy to do.

Comment: Keeping modules short is of course a very good idea. But to get the benefit of always having "import information" for functions available, the maximum module length would have to be one screen (probably 100 lines max). And that would probably be too short to be practical in most cases.

Comment: I suppose you could take this to a logical extreme.  I think there might be a balance point where your module is "small enough" that you don't need fancy import techniques to manage complexity.  Our average module size is -- coincidentally -- about 100 lines.

Answer (score 10):

One thing to bear in mind:  needless imports can cause performance problems.  So if this is a function that will be called frequently, you're better off just putting the import at the top.  Of course this *is* an optimization, so if there's a valid case to be made that importing inside a function is more clear than importing at the top of a file, that trumps performance in most cases.

If you're doing IronPython, I'm told that it's better to import inside functions (since compiling code in IronPython can be slow).  Thus, you may be able to get a way with importing inside functions then.  But other than that, I'd argue that it's just not worth it to fight convention.

> As a general rule, I do this if there is an import that is only used within a single function.

Another point I'd like to make is that this may be a potential maintenence problem.  What happens if you add a function that uses a module that was previously used by only one function?  Are you going to remember to add the import to the top of the file?  Or are you going to scan each and every function for imports?

FWIW, there are cases where it makes sense to import inside a function.  For example, if you want to set the language in cx_Oracle, you need to set an NLS`_`LANG environment variable *before* it is imported.  Thus, you may see code like this:

```
import os

oracle = None

def InitializeOracle(lang):
    global oracle
    os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = lang
    import cx_Oracle
    oracle = cx_Oracle
```

Comment: I agree with your maintenence issue. Refactoring code can be a bit problematic. If I add a second function that uses a module previously used only by one function - I either move the import to the top, or I break my own general rule by importing the module in the second function as well.

Comment: I think the performance argument can go the other way too. Importing a module can be time-consuming. On distributed file systems like those on supercomputers, importing a big module like numpy can take several seconds. If a module is only needed for a single, rarely used function, then importing in the function will speed up the common case significantly.

Answer (score 6):

I've broken this rule before for modules that are self-testing.  That is, they are normally just used for support,  but I define a main for them so that if you run them by themselves you can test their functionality.  In that case I sometimes import `getopt` and `cmd` just in main, because I want it to be clear to someone reading the code that these modules have nothing to do with the normal operation of the module and are only being included for testing.

Answer (score 5):

Coming from the question about [loading the module twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077381/what-happens-when-i-import-module-twice-in-python) - Why not both?

An import at the top of the script will indicate the dependencies and another import in the function with make this function more atomic, while seemingly not causing any performance disadvantage, since a consecutive import is cheap.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the alternative approach that's used in sqlalchemy: dependency injection:

```
@util.dependencies("sqlalchemy.orm.query")
def merge_result(query, *args):
    #...
    query.Query(...)
```

Notice how the imported library is declared in a decorator, and passed *as an argument to the function*!

This approach makes the code cleaner, and also works **4.5 times faster** than an `import` statement!

Benchmark: https://gist.github.com/kolypto/589e84fbcfb6312532658df2fabdb796

Answer (score 5):

There's another (probably "corner") case where it may be beneficial to `import` inside rarely used functions: shorten startup time.

I hit that wall once with a rather complex program running on a small IoT server accepting commands from a serial line and performing operations, possibly very complex operations.

Placing `import` statements at top of files meant to have *all* imports processed before server start; since `import` list included `jinja2`, `lxml`, `signxml` and other "heavy weights" (and SoC was not very powerful) this meant *minutes* before the first instruction was actually executed.

OTOH placing most imports in functions I was able to have the server "alive" on the serial line in seconds. Of course when the modules were actually needed I had to pay the price (Note: also this can be mitigated by spawning a background task doing `import`s in idle time).

Comment: This is also an issue with command-line programs which may take seconds just to print their help message, because of time spent importing stuff that is not necessary to print the help message!

Answer (score 3):

As long as it's `import` and not `from x import *`, you should put them at the top. It adds just one name to the global namespace, and you stick to PEP 8. Plus, if you later need it somewhere else, you don't have to move anything around.

It's no big deal, but since there's almost no difference I'd suggest doing what PEP 8 says.

Comment: Actually, putting `from x import *` inside a function will generate a SyntaxWarning, at least in 2.5.

Answer (score 3):

In modules that are both 'normal' modules and can be executed (i.e. have a `if __name__ == '__main__':`-section), I usually import modules that are only used when executing the module inside the main section.

Example:

```
def really_useful_function(data):
    ...


def main():
    from pathlib import Path
    from argparse import ArgumentParser
    from dataloader import load_data_from_directory

    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('directory')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    data = load_data_from_directory(Path(args.directory))
    print(really_useful_function(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```