# When and how often is a nested import performed?

Tags: python, function, namespaces, nested, python-import

Given code such as

```
def norm(x, y):
    from math import sqrt
    return sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
```

nesting the `import` in the function keeps the outer namespace clear. However, does the `import` actually occur on *every* call to the function and thus decrease performance or only on the first call and then somehow cached?

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks, but then at least close it as duplicate of the _open_ question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-python-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module of which _that_ is considered a duplicate...

Comment: ...though personally I like [Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3095167/321973) best

Comment: I was actually the one who first suggested the duplicate. I found the question (especially "Does it re-import every time the function is run, or perhaps just once at the beginning whether or not the function is run?") and its answers to be more relevant to your question than the question it is a duplicate of.

Comment: @Karin Thanks, upon closer inspection that makes sense.