# how to use while loop without infinite loop(python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been trying to create a program with python 2.7. 
This program creates a random number. (`nlist[r]` is saved in `list[]`)

If `list[0]` is `'do'` or `'ge'` or `'gi'`, just print `list` and the program is ended.

If `list[0]` is `'mo'` or `'yu'`, the `while` loop starts.

When `list[k]=='yu'` or `'mo'`, the loop must stop, print `list`, and also end the program.
But this ended up in an infinite while loop...

Here is my code:

```
nlist=['do','ge','gi','yu','mo']
list=[]
def playYut():
    import random
    r=random.randrange(0,5)
    list.append(nlist[r])

playYut()

if list[0]=='do' or list[0]=='gae' or list[0]=='girl':
    for i in list:
        print i
else:
    k=0
    while list[k]:
        if list[k]=='yut' or list[k]=='mo':
            playYut()
            for i in list:
                print i
        else:
            for i in list:
                print i
```

Comment: you are not incrementing `k` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few changes in your code which i will be explaining below.

```
import random
nlist=['do','ge','gi','yu','mo']
check_list = ['do','ge','gi']
loop_check_list = ['yu' ,'mo' ]
flag =1
your_list=[]
k=0
def playYut():
    r=random.randrange(0,5)
    your_list.append(nlist[r])
playYut()

if your_list[0] in check_list:
    print list1

elif your_list[0] in loop_check_list:
    while flag==1:
        k+=1
        playYut()
        if your_list[k] in loop_check_list:
            print your_list
            flag=0
```

1) Let **import** statements be declared at the top of the program it's good practice. Check this out for a detail explanation.

[In Python, what happens when you import inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095071/in-python-what-happens-when-you-import-inside-of-a-function)

2) Instead of this

> if your_list[0]=='do' or your_list[0]=='gae' or your_list[0]=='girl':

this is more elegant to look at.

> if your_list[0] in some_list_with_those_values:

3) Also instead of naming a list as **list** define some 
   variable name for it. For ex **your_list**.

4) Also you can use either **break** or a  **flag variable** but i prefer using flag variable here. Understanding them is essential. Set a flag variable with a value say **1** and change it to **0** when the condition is changed. This way you can exit out of the while loop.

5) I don't clearly understand what you want to do with your program. But from your description this a working code that you might want.

Comment: your statement 2 is a bit misleading. OP's statement is perfectly fine. Also if you are going to give an answer please point out that `list` is a bad variable name to use instead of just changing it to `list1`

Comment: @MooingRawr thanks for pointing it out man. Got confused a bit!!. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a very common mistake you did there, my friend. You have to change the value of `k` for looping or add a `break` statement for stoping the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the value of k in every loop
you can do so by adding

```
K+=1
```

or

```
k=k+1
```