# Any reason to put import library as class attribute?

Tags: python, class

may I know what is main reason for me to make decision if I should put `datetime` as class attribution or not? lets say if I know `class Test2` is single class and definitely does not have plan to be inherited by any class

Is it correct to use as class `Test2` does where it does not set any `import` as class attribute or ?

### test1.py

```
import datetime

class Test1:
    datetime = datetime
    def getnow(self):
        return self.datetime.time()
```

### test2.py

```
import datetime

datetime = datetime
class Test2:
    def getnow(self):
        return datetime.time()
```

Comment: Test2 is better, there's no point in making a class variable something that you're going to use as a global anyway. However in Test2 do note that `datetime = datetime` is superfluous.

Comment: Why did you think there *would* be a reason to do that?

Comment: short answer - no reason

Comment: I don't understand either example. Why `datetime = datetime`in test2?

Comment: yap... there should not have any reason for `datetime = datetime` neither

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these implementations has any real benefit.

In test2.py, `datetime = datetime` is essentially a no-op. It does not change the state of the module. This is completely useless.

test1.py doesn't actually behave particularly differently, either. It just sets `datetime` as a class attribute, which means that it looks to the class to find `datetime` instead of the module. This *might* perform better in some very heavy load circumstances, but not enough that you should be worried about it unless you already know what you're doing.

The fact they invoke `self.datetime.time()`, though, suggests to me that the author's (assuming you saw someone doing this in their own code) intention was that `datetime` could be *temporarily replaced* at runtime, like this:

```
class FakeDatetime:
    def time(self):
        return 'from fake datetime'

t = Test1()
t.datetime = FakeDatetime()
print(t.getnow()) # Prints "from fake datetime"
```

To me, this looks like a misguided attempt to enable using a **mock** or **stub** for automated tests. They probably intend for it to be used something like this:

```
import unittest
from test1 import Test1

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_method():
        mock = MyMock()
        expected_value = 'my value'
        # Set up code to make mock.time() return expected value

        t = Test1()
        t.datetime = mock
        assert t.time() == expected_value
```

The standard solution to mocking in Python is the [`unittest.mock` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) (or the [`mock` package](https://pypi.org/project/mock/) if using Python 3.2 or older). This module encourages *patching* to replace dependencies, rather than something manual like the code you presented:

**test3.py**

```
import datetime

class Test3:
    def getnow(self):
        return datetime.time()
```

**test3tests.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from test3 import Test3

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('test3.datetime')
    def test_my_method(datetime_mock):
        expected_value = 'my value'
        datetime_mock.time.return_value = expected_value

        t = Test3()
        assert t.time() == expected_value
        # Original datetime is restored by patch automatically when method exits
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the subject did you mean?

**this**

```
import datetime

class Test1:
    datetime = datetime
    def getnow(self):
        return self.datetime.time()
```

**vs. this**

```
class Test2:
import datetime

    datetime = datetime
    def getnow(self):
        return self.datetime.time()
```

It appears your imports should be at the top of your python file.  So, in that case, Test1 is the correct way to go.

[In Python, what happens when you import inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095071/in-python-what-happens-when-you-import-inside-of-a-function)

"In general practice, it's probably not that beneficial. In fact, most Python style guides encourage programmers to place all imports at the beginning of the module file."

Comment: Neither case serves any purpose, though. There is no need to do this.

Comment: I wasn't focusing on what the code was doing.   I was simply looking at it from a language syntax and best practice standpoint.   Where do the imports got?

Comment: The import goes at the top of the file, and then all other re-binding of `datetime` can go. If you want `getnow` to return the current time, just `return datetime.datetime.now()` but there's no need for it to be a class attribute.

Comment: So you are saying that this can be accomplished with two lines of code. <br/><br/>    `import datetime  <br/>return self.datetime.time()`

Comment: Well, 1 after the import, depending on whether you even need your own class. The user-defined class isn't necessary at all. But I'm not sure why exactly you are asking; I'm not suggesting that you need change your answer, but are you unsure about this yourself?

Comment: I get your point now, the class is not needed, I think it was not a very clear question and I am making assumptions with my answer.   Also the example provided could be legit if was simply a sample.   Again I was focusing on answering the question, where do import statements belong.

Comment: my question is not about where I should put import datetime. My question is about if I need to use datetime as class attribution. but still thanks for your answer

Comment: @A.Lee  No problem, I will read more on this thread.  I will read the other answers.  Sorry I wasn't able to answer it for you.