# Can you perform an inline import in Python?

Tags: python, import

Say you only wanted to call a regular expression a single time in you code. As far as I am aware, this means that you then need to do `import re` somewhere before your call of a function from `re`. Is it possible to combine this with the function call, in-line?
I thought maybe something like this would work

```py
print(import re; re.search(r'<regex>', <string>).group())
```

but it just threw an error saying invalid syntax at the point of the import. This leads me to believe that the only way to do this is

```py
import re
print(re.search(r'<regex>'), <string>).group())
```

Comment: Correct. Do a global import

Comment: What's more, you gain nothing from `from module_x import method_y` for runtime efficiency. Don't bother, if that's your only motivator

Comment: If the code will be seldom called, you could import inside of a function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095071/in-python-what-happens-when-you-import-inside-of-a-function
Doing single-line operations with a `;` are just dirty in python and I would avoid them altogether

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question:

> Can You Perform an Inline Import in Python?

You can use the built-in [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) module:

```
print(importlib.import_module('re').search("h", "hello").group())
```

Output:

```
'h'
```

Of course, it would require you to import the `importlib` module first:

```
import importlib

print(importlib.import_module('re').search("h", "hello").group())
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

> The `import_module()` function acts as a simplifying wrapper around `importlib.__import__()`. This means all semantics of the function are derived from `importlib.__import__()`. The most important difference between these two functions is that `import_module()` returns the specified package or module (e.g. pkg.mod), while `__import__()` returns the top-level package or module (e.g. pkg).

Answer (score 1):

E.g. Use like this:

```bash
python -c 'import cyrtranslit; print(cyrtranslit.to_latin("бла-бла-бла", "ru"))'
```

Or like this:

```bash
python -c 'import cyrtranslit,sys; print(cyrtranslit.to_latin(sys.argv[1], "ru"))' 'бла-бла-бла'
```

Result: `bla-bla-bla`

Or like this:

```bash
python -c 'import sys; from urllib import parse; print(parse.unquote(sys.argv[1]))' 'bla%20bla%20bla'
```

Result: `bla bla bla`