# Is it bad practice in Python to define a function in the middle of operational code?

Tags: python, function, coding-style, pep

I learned from [a similar question on imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188640/good-or-bad-practice-in-python-import-in-the-middle-of-a-file) that one should not mix "operational code" and `import` (they should be at the top).

What is the consensus around defining functions in the middle of "operational code"?

I have a case where a function is used in just one place (it has to be a function) and having its definition close to that piece of code would make sense (all would be grouped together). It visually breaks the flow of the code, though.

Any advice from PEP? (I did not find anything relevant, as opposed to `import`)

**EDIT**: the apparent trend in the answers is that it is not a nice thing to do, but unlike the `import`case mentioned above there are no definitive directives (PEP for instance)

Comment: I usually only do it if I need to close over some variable only available in the containing function's scope.

Comment: Voted to close since you are likely to get as many different answers as there are people, and none of the answers so far have cited any source other than "in my opinion." My take on the matter: I define functions in the middle of operational code when the thing I want to do is too complex for a lambda, but too specific to be a general function that others can make use of. It's along the lines of `do stuff; and more stuff; by the way, here's how you remove invalid characters for a string; remove invalid characters for all strings; do other stuff`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All code in a python script or module (which is basically the same thing - the difference being how it is used) is "operational code" one way or another. The clean way to structure a script's code is to have *everything* in functions - what you name "operational code" being in a "main()" function - and just have a call to that "main" function *if* the module is used as a script, ie:

```
# mymoduleorscript.py
import something
from somewhere import somethingelse

def somefunc(arg1, arg2):
   # ...

def otherfunc(arga, argb):
   # ...

def main(*args):
   # "operational" code here
   return status_code # 0 if ok, anything else if error

# only call main if used as a script
if __name__ == "__main__":
     import sys
     sys.exit(main(*sys.argv[1:]))
```

Note that this is *not* a "in my opinion" answer, but the officially blessed OneTrueWay of doing things.

Comment: Isn't your `import sys` in violation of [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)?

Comment: @WoJ wel technically yes, but when I only need `sys` for the main I tend to keep it there.

Answer (score 4):

Unless it's really necessary, i prefer to put all of it at the top of my script, since it makes finding them easier - more readable - and neater as well.

I think this starts to be pretty important if your code is going to be read by others, you don't want them to be confused when they want to see the functions, or how your code is operating.

Also, breaking down your program to smaller pieces, especially for long, long code is a good idea. When you have to deal with either part, you can do it quickly. So for me, the top is for declarations, and the bottom is for operational code. :)

I don't know why, but i feel like appending this here:

```
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
...
```

Comment: umm.. Why downvote? This is not meta..

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure if this is right or wrong as I am another newbie here. But I have implemented some thing like this in my code which will import in between the operational code.

code:

```
import os,importlib,

l  = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
x = [m.split('.')[0] for m in l if m.endswith('.py')] #  list all the py files in the direcory.

modules = []
for mod in x: 
    modules.append(importlib.import_module(mod)) # I am importing them using a for loop
```

I seriously dont know this is what you are looking for. But I will be glad if it can help you in any way... and I ll leave the commenting on best programming practices to the wizards here :)

Comment: He wants to know if it is good or bad. Not how :)

Comment: BTW, did you run your code? There is an extra comma at the end of import

Comment: @Sarvan, `all the py files` are Python modules ...

Comment: I ve given only a part of my code here might that cause some errors.. but its working fine for me. there is nothing wrong to say how when we dont know why even and i ve commented the same in my answer. - thefourtheye

Comment: i didnt get your point - Oz123

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your operational code is too long, which leads to the fact that if you define that function before your operational code then it is too far from where it is called.

Having a very long piece of code is usually not a good idea, not only in Python. My suggestion is that find out some way to split your long piece of operational code into modules (functions or classes).

Comment: The problem? What problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion keeping the functions out of the operational code is good for two reasons:

1. It increases the readability of your program as in your operational
   code you can just call the function instead of stuffing the function
   between other expressions/statements. It makes the program look more cleaner as well.
2. Stuffing the functions between your operational code spoils the structure of the program        and makes the code look more complex

Answer (score 0):

I could see that sometimes this might relate to "[flat is better than nested](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)". For example,

```
def dist(x, y):
    return abs(x - y)

for a, v in ls1:
    ls2.append(dist(a, b))
```

vs

```
for a, v in ls1:
    def dist(x, y):
        return abs(x - y)

    ls2.append(dist(a, b))
```

Personally I do sometimes mix functions and operational code. I don't see any specific PEP against it, but general considerations of code organization should still be taken into account.