# Python: When making a function, where do I put my "import" stuff?

Tags: python

I'm making a function for an assignment right now, and I used "sys" and 'random' in the function. I was just wondering where the most acceptable place is to put the "import ___" is when you're making a function? I wanted to know for future reference if it's better to put the "import" inside your function, or if it should stay outside.

Answer (score 1):

Put your imports at the top of the file.

The only time it really makes sense to `import` things anywhere else, is if you're doing so conditionally, to see if said library exists for example.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1188672/119527):

> [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) authoritatively states:
>
> > Imports are always put at the top of
> >     the file, just after any module
> >           comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

Answer (score 0):

From PEP 8:
`Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.`

More [pep8 imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)