# Can I import a module in the middle of a code?

Tags: python

I am aware there've been [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188640/good-or-bad-practice-in-python-import-in-the-middle-of-a-file) on this topic. My case might be kind of 'special'. My code `bar.py` needs to use a module, let's say, `foo`. The general usage of `bar.py` is something like this:

```
python bar.py --threads 3 --dir jjj
```

The issue is that loading `foo` takes a long time(~40s), so I want to check the correctness of the arguments before loading it. Does it make sense to put `import foo` later in the code instead of at the top?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 6):

You can technically import a module wherever you like, but note that it will become a *local* name; if imported in the middle of a class or function then it will be in *only* that scope, not in global (module) scope.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in Python you are allowed to import modules anywhere you like in a Python file. However, the *scope* matters. For example, if you `import foo` globally the module is available globally, like so:

```
import foo

# you can use `foo` here

def main():
    # you can use `foo` here too

# ...
```

However, if you import inside of a class or function, that module is only available within that scope. For example:

```
def main():
    import foo

    # `foo` is available here (scope of `foo`)

    def validate_something():
        # `foo` is available here because `validate_something` has a child scope of the `main` function's scope

def parse_args():
    # `foo` is not available here (scope of `parse_args`)

# `foo` is also not available here (the global scope)
```

Now, in your "special" case, yes it would be ideal to delay the import until the arguments are parsed and validated. The only downside to imports in the middle of a file are organization, but this is a necessary trade-off in scenarios that make sense.