# using import inside class

Tags: python, class, import

I am completely new to the python class concept. After searching for a solution for some days, I hope I will get help here:

I want a python class where I import a function and use it there. The main code should be able to call the function from the class. for that I have two files in the same folder.

---

Thanks to @cdarke, @DeepSpace and @MosesKoledoye, I edited the mistake, but sadly that wasn't it.

I still get the Error:

```
test 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    foo.doit()
  File "/Users/ls/Documents/Entwicklung/RaspberryPi/test/test.py", line 8, in doit
    self.timer(5)
  File "/Users/ls/Documents/Entwicklung/RaspberryPi/test/test.py", line 6, in timer
    zeit.sleep(2)
NameError: global name 'zeit' is not defined
```

---

---

@wombatz got the right tip: 
it must be self.zeit.sleep(2) or Test.zeit.sleep(2). the import could be also done above the class declaration.

---

**Test.Py**

```
class Test:
    import time as zeit
    def timer(self, count):
        for i in range(count):
            print("test "+str(i))
            self.zeit.sleep(2)      <-- self is importent, otherwise, move the import above the class declaration
    def doit(self):
        self.timer(5)
```

and

**run.py**

```
from test import Test
foo = Test()
foo.doit()
```

when I try to `python run.py` I get this error:

```
test 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    foo.doit()
  File "/Users/ls/Documents/Entwicklung/RaspberryPi/test/test.py", line 8, in doit
    self.timer(5)
  File "/Users/ls/Documents/Entwicklung/RaspberryPi/test/test.py", line 6, in timer
    sleep(2)
NameError: global name 'sleep' is not defined
```

What I understand from the error is that the import in the class is not recognized. But how can I achive that the import in the class is recognized?

Comment: You probably mean `zeit.sleep(2)`

Comment: @cdarke actually `zeit.sleep`, since OP uses `as`

Comment: @DeepSpace: my edit crossed over your comment.  Thanks

Comment: thanks, i corrected the mistake, but i did not help - see my edit.

Comment: The `sleep(2)` shown in your second traceback from `python run.py` doesn't match what you say is in `test.py` — which has `zeit.sleep(2)` on that line.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Everything defined inside the *namespace* of a class has to be accessed from that class. That holds for methods, variables, nested classes and everything else including modules.

If you really want to import a module inside a class you must access it from that class:

```
class Test:
    import time as zeit
    def timer(self):
        self.zeit.sleep(2)
        # or Test.zeit.sleep(2)
```

But why would you import the module inside the class anyway? I can't think of a use case for that despite from wanting it to put into that namespace.

You really should move the import to the top of the module. Then you can call `zeit.sleep(2)` inside the class without prefixing `self` or `Test`.

Also you should not use non-english identifiers like `zeit`. People who only speak english should be able to read your code.

Comment: @syntonym I'm sorry I don't quite understand. Could you please show me an example?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood you. I thought you meant that you always have to use `self.attribute` in a class, which is of course not true because you can use things like globals or builtins (like print). But you meant that objects defined in the namespace of the class are not accessible from class-bound functions automatically.

Comment: @syntonym yes, I should clarify that, thanks for the hint.

Comment: This is currently the only answer that addresses the OP question.

Comment: One use case that I have encountered is when using TensorFlow with multiprocessing. It only works when each worker imports its own copy of TensorFlow.

Comment: @Wombatz My use case was when the file contained multiple classes grouped by topic, but only one of them requiring machine learning. For users who want to import other classes without installing machine learning packages (they don't use them anyway), it is practical to compartmentalize the imports to the classes that do use them. Of course, storing the classes in separate files would be a feasible alternative solution.

Comment: I have a use case where my class has the option to use convole from scipy vs filter from opencv.  By doing the import during the class initialization, the user can have control over the dependencies required.

Comment: Another use-case would be when you'll have to mock a module-class using `pytest` `fixtures` and `fixture` would need to be applied before the package is imported. You can apply `fixtures` to the test class but you would still need to import packages inside each functions which is pretty annoying if you have many of them.

Comment: Multiprocessing in general can be a reason. For example, I'm running a visualization process which needs to import its own dependencies, but they should not be imported in the main process.

Comment: in mypy it gives `Unsupported class scoped import` is it normal?

Answer (score 4):

`sleep` is not a python builtin, and the name as is, does not reference any object. So Python has rightly raised a `NameEror`.

You intend to:

```
import time as zeit

zeit.sleep(2)
```

And move `import time as zeit` to the top of the module.

The `time` module aliased as `zeit` is probably not appearing in your module's global symbol table because it was imported inside a `class`.

Comment: thanks, i corrected the mistake, but i did not help - see my edit.

Comment: @ludwigschuster see my update: move `import time as zeit` to the top of the module.

Answer (score 3):

You want [time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=sleep#time.sleep%20). You can also use;

```
from time import sleep
```

Edit: Importing within class scope issues explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6883558/5757280).

Comment: thanks, i corrected the mistake, but i did not help - see my edit.

Comment: @ludwigschuster You should read through the answer linked here. There is no reason to have the import within your class. It should go at the top of your module. (Note - there are exceptions to this for modules that require special initialization before being imported, but that is rare and definitely not the case with the `time` module)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there! `sleep` is a function within the `time` module. This means that the name `sleep` doesn't exist unless its understood within the context of `time`, unless you define it on your own. Since you didn't define it on your own, you can access it by running `time.sleep(2)`.

In your specific example, you used:

```
import time as zeit
```

you'll have to run:

```
zeit.sleep(2)
```

Alternatively, you can import sleep directly from time, by running:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
```

Good luck!

You can read more about the time module here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

You can learn more about imports here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

and I highly recommend learning about namespace in python, here: https://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/

Comment: thanks, i corrected the mistake, but i did not help - see my edit.

Comment: move the import statement above the class definition. the `import time as zeit` should be above the `class Test:` line.

Comment: @ludwigschuster, have you been able to try this?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Wombatz on his solution, but I do not have enough reputation to comment on his question

One use case that I have found for importing a module within a class is when I want to initialize a class from a config file.

Say my config file is

***config.py***

```
__all__ = ['logfile', ... ]
logfile = 'myevent.log'
...
```

And in my main module

***do_something.py***

```
class event():
    from config import *

    def __init__(self):
        try : self.logfile
        except NameError: self.logfile = './generic_event.log'
```

Now the advantage of this scheme is that we do not need to import logfile in the global namespace if it is not needed

Whereas, importing at the beginning of do_something.py, I will have to use globals inside the class, which is a little ugly in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bit late, but I agree with idea of not polluting the module-level namespace (of course this can probably be remedied with a better design of a module, plus 'explicit is better than implicit' anyways).

Here is what I would do. The basic idea is this: `import` is an implicit assignment in which an entire module object gets assigned to a single name. Thus:

```
class Test:
    import time as zeit
    
    self.zeit = zeit # This line binds the module object to an attribute of an instance created from the class
    
    def timer(self, count):
        for i in range(count):
            print("test "+str(i))
            self.zeit.sleep(2) # This necessitates the `zeit` attribute within the instance created from the class
    
    def doit(self):
        self.timer(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import importlib



class importery():
    def __init__(self, y,z):
        self.my_name = y
        self.pathy = z
        self.spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(self.my_name, self.pathy)
        x = importlib.util.module_from_spec(self.spec)
        self.spec.loader.exec_module(x)
        print(dir(x))
    
        root = x.Tk()
        root.mainloop()
    
    

pathy = r'C:\Users\mine\Desktop\python310\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py'

importery('tk', pathy)
```

There is a ***'time and a place'*** to do this type of black magic, thankfully very rare times and places. Of the few I've found I've normally been able to use subprocess to get some other flavor of python to do my dirty work, but that is not always an option.

Now, I have 'used' this in blender when I've needed to have conflicting versions of a module loaded at the same time. This is not a good way to do things and really should be a last resort.

If you are a blender user and you happen to decide to commit this sin, I suggest doing so in a clean version of blender, install a like version of python next to it to use that to do your pip installs with, and please make sure you have added your config folder to your blender folder, else this black magic may come back to bite you in the arse later.