# Where to place the import statements in Django?

Tags: django

I have a lot of import statements in my views.py.

Does it help in terms of performance if instead putting all of the imports at the beginning of the file I put the imports in the views exactly where they are needed?

Having them in the particular view where they are needed helps also if you for example have to remove a view you don't have to scroll up and remove the unneeded imports.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it help in terms of performance if instead putting all of the imports at the beginning of the file I put the imports in the views exactly where they are needed?

No. If all imports will be placed at the beginning of the file, the import is performed only once - when the django-process starts.

Comment: And what if I put the imports in the view functions? Does this mean that the Python tries to import (but doesn't) every-time the view is called?

Comment: If shortly: The module will be imported one time, but the function will be performed a little slower. See detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-python-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module