# Python math flashcard program

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to teach myself Python. I've started to write a little flashcard script. My idea is that the user is presented with a problem and is prompted to submit an answer. If the answer is incorrect the user is prompted to try again, an so on until the correct answer is entered. So far it works as planned, but I don't know how to make it start over again after the correct answer is entered. 
I suppose I'll also need to include some means of allowing the user to exit the game, which I also don't know how to do so if you want to throw in a suggestion about that I'd appreciate it. :-)

PS - If my code is lame I'm open to suggestions. But I'm mainly looking for an answer to my original question(s). This is my first foray into coding so I'm sure as time goes on I'll get better at writing more elegant code.

Thanks!

```
def add():
   from random import randint
   a = randint(1, 5)
   b = randint(1, 5)
   c = a + b
   print a,  '+',  b
   print 'What\'s the sum?'
   d = input()
   while d != c:
     print 'Wrong, try again!'
     d = input()
   else:
     print "Correct!"
```

Comment: you could simplify the loop to `while input() != c`, and remove the first `d = input()`

Comment: congrats on your foray into programming!  looking good so far  :)

Comment: You should not put the import inside your definition generally.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-python-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, use `raw_input` instead of `input` and then convert that to an integer. To answer your question though, ask for user input like so:

```
play_again = raw_input('Play again? (y/n)')
if play_again.lower().startswith('y'):
    add()
return
```

`input` is unsafe because it gets evaluated as native code, and so a skilled individual may be able to hack into the system. `raw_input` treats the input as a string, and you can call `int()` on the result.

This only applies for Python 2 however. For Python 3, `input` is fine - it replaced the Python 2 `raw_input`.

Also, there is recursion in the function - although nobody will probably be persistent enough to make the stack overflow, although for other applications, iteration will be the best method.

Converting this to an iterative loop is trivial (and also recommended). Put everything apart from the import inside a `while True` loop. Then at the end of the loop, add this code:

```
play_again = raw_input('Play again? (y/n)')
if play_again.lower().startswith('y'):
    continue
break
```

You could of course check for `'n'` instead of `'y'` and get rid of the `continue`, replacing it with a simple `break` statement.

Note that you can also replace the `if` statement to a less readable:

```
if raw_input('Play again? (y/n)').lower().startswith('y'):  # or 'n'
```

And get rid of the intermediate `play_again` variable. Although I wouldn't sacrifice readability for compactibility.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee the OP uses `print` as a statement, so I assume it's Python 2. However, it is worth to note the difference.

Comment: `continue` isn't going to work as a variable name.. ;^)  More importantly, though, using a `while` loop is preferable to a possibly interpreter-breaking recursive call.

Comment: @DSM how did I forget that? Probably need more sleep. `:P`

Comment: Would be better if a loop is used instead of recursion, as in a game loop

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 (for input) :

I slightly modified your code (added "()" for print, and int in order for comparison to work. Didn't check if you enter a non int)

```
def add():
   from random import randint
   a = randint(1, 5)
   b = randint(1, 5)
   c = a + b
   print (a,  '+',  b)
   d = int(input('What\'s the sum?'))
   while d != c:
     print ('Wrong, try again!')
     print (a,  '+',  b,' ? ')
     d = int(input())
   else:
     print ("Correct!")


while True:
    add()
    if input('Continue (O/N) ? ') == 'N':
        break
```

I printed also the addition in your loop because many wrong answers can clear the initial question.

As stated, the initial loop execute your function until you type 'N'.
You might add the correct answer in the add loop if the user wants to quit.