# Save NumPy array / vector to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have some numeric numbers ( about 550,000) and I tried to save them in a CSV file. My values can only be 1 or 2. But it is saved as:

```
['2.000000000000000000e+00']
['1.000000000000000000e+00']
['2.000000000000000000e+00']
['2.000000000000000000e+00']
...
```

My code is:

```
import numpy as np

def save_in_scv_format(My_Labels):
    K = []
    for i in range(len(My_Labels)):
        K.append(My_Labels[i])

    np.savetxt('My_labels.csv', K, delimiter = ',')
```

`My_labels` is a vector having integer values of 1 or 2 with length 550,000.

How can I save these values as either a `1` or a `2`?

Comment: What is the format you want?  The integer representation (e.g. `1`,`2`,`3`), separated by commas?  Like what `print(','.join(K))` shows?

Comment: If you do not say what output format you want, I cannot tell you how to get it :-(

Comment: @jedwards @ Serge : I want to have a vector of [1,2,2,2,1,.....,2,1,1] when I read the file and put the values in a list.

Comment: The default format parameter is `fmt='%.18e`, which is why you are getting 18 trailing zeros. You want to pass `fmt=%d` if you just want `int`s

Comment: Also, as jedwards points out, there is no need to build a list from your numpy array.

Comment: And finally, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-python-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module) thread regarding putting `import` statements inside your functions. What do you mean by vector, anyway? What type is My_Labels? Is it not a numpy array?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the formatting of numeric values in the output. From the [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

> **fmt** : `str or sequence of strs, optional`
>
> ```
>    A single format (%10.5f), a sequence of formats, or a multi-format string,
>    e.g. ‘Iteration %d – %10.5f’, in which case delimiter is ignored.
> ```

So try:

```
np.savetxt('My_labels.csv', K, delimiter = ',', fmt='%d')
```

However, there are other problems with this code.

```
import numpy as np

def save_in_csv_format(My_Labels):
    np.savetxt('My_labels.csv', My_Labels, delimiter = ',', fmt='%d')
```

This should do exactly the same thing, and be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to point out, assuming `My_Labels` is a list as you suggest, the indicated section of your code is superfluous:

```
def save_in_scv_format(My_Labels):
    import numpy as np
    K  = []                                 # <--
    for i in range(len(My_Labels)):         # <--
            K.append(My_Labels[i])          # <--

    np.savetxt('My_labels.csv', K, delimiter = ',')
```

You'd be just as well off writing:

```
def save_in_scv_format(My_Labels):
    import numpy as np

    np.savetxt('My_labels.csv', My_Labels, delimiter = ',')
```

But I don't think you need numpy to do what it seems you want to do.  Something like:

```
def save_in_scv_format(My_Labels):
    with open('My_labels.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write(','.join(My_Labels))
```

would likely work, and better.

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
def save_in_scv_format(My_Labels):
    with open('My_labels.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(My_Labels))
```

which would preserve the enclosing square brackets, and add spaces between the integers.

There is also the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) modules, you might look into, for alternative means of outputting your list to a file.

n.b. If I misunderstood, and `My_Labels` is, for example, a numpy array, then something like:

```
my_array = My_Labels.tolist()
```

([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)) is a cleaner way of creating a python list.

Comment: Do you think saving this in an excel file is better or saving that in a text file? previously I tried to save it into a text file but later I was not able to open the text file.

Comment: A text file is much easier to create, and much easier to read back into Python later.  If you create a proper .csv file (e.g. using the csv module), you can import that into excel as well and it will split the integers into columns, removing the commas.

Comment: The input is a NumPy `ndarray`; using `.savetxt()` is appropriate here.