# Can I force `import mymodule` to only import definitions and classes, and not modules (dependencies) imported in the first few lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, scope

I'm a beginner to python, and have written a module that looks something like this:

```
# filename: mymodule.py
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
def a():
   ...<stuff>...
def b():
   ...<stuff>...
```

The consensus in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-python-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module) generally (and in agreement with PEP8) seems to be that import statements should be at the file header. However, now when I `import mymodule`, running `dir(mymodule)` shows that objects `np` and `datetime` are part of `mymodule` -- which offhand, seems inefficient and "sloppy". It seems one way to preserve **only** classes and defs would be some kind of conditional deletion via dynamic iteration over `globals()` (which after trying and failing for a bit, seems *really* elusive), or just use the `del` keyword on everything.

---

**The main question**: can I do this, and can I do this dynamically instead of explicitly? Don't the `def`s work independently, regardless of whether the header modules are part of the import? Otherwise `from <x> import <y>` would break every time, I would think.

Comment: Why do you think having other modules is inefficient?

Comment: Isn't it just sort of messy? I guess that's my main gripe. What I mean is, say I have in some python script `import mymodule as my; import numpy as np`. Now there are two copies of `numpy` taking up memory -- `numpy` and `mymodule.np`. Although I suppose it's a very small amount of space.

Comment: No. Both `numpy` and `mymodule.np` refer to the same entry in `sys.modules`.

Comment: ...oh. I forgot that I don't know anything about anything. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielRoseman So is this just accepted practice, to let the external module reference propagate into a separately imported module? It seems to me that this is not the "correct way", because importing standard libraries like `sys`, `os`, and `numpy` shows there are not alien module names in `dir(np)`, `dir(os)`, etc. Maybe this works by, for any file with lots of `class`es and `def`s, **always** using name-explicit `from x import y`s in the `__init__.py` file?