# How can I use python to display the coordinate of points on the scene by clicking the points?

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I have displayed the 3D geometry of a model with python and mayavi using spyder successfully.

Now I am faced with a question that I want to click the point of the model to display the information about the point on the scene; NOT just print it.

Is there any way or any functions about it?

Here is the code I have done:

```
from mayavi import mlab
import meshio
import numpy 

def ReadGmshNodes(file,nbcoord):
    import scipy
    f=open(file,'r')
    i=0
    goodline=0
    nbnodes=0
    for l in f:
        s=l.split()
        if (goodline==1):
            if (nbnodes==0):
                nbnodes=int(s[0])
                nodes=scipy.zeros((nbnodes,nbcoord))
            else:
                if (i<nbnodes):
                    if nbcoord==3:
                        nodes[i,0]=float(s[1])
                        nodes[i,1]=float(s[2])
                        nodes[i,2]=float(s[3])
                        i=i+1

                    if nbcoord==2:
                        nodes[i,0]=float(s[1])
                        nodes[i,1]=float(s[2])
                        i=i+1

        if ( s[0]=='$Nodes' ):
            goodline=1
    f.close()
    return nodes                

def ReadGmshDisplacements(file):
    import scipy
    f=open(file,'r')
    i=0
    goodline=0
    nbnodes=0
    j=0
    for l in f:
        s=l.split()
        if (goodline==1):
            j=j+1
            if (j==8):
                nbnodes=int(s[0])
                displacements=scipy.zeros((nbnodes,3))
            if (j>8):
                if (i<nbnodes):
                    displacements[i,0]=float(s[1])
                    displacements[i,1]=float(s[2])
                    displacements[i,2]=float(s[3])
                    i=i+1

        if ( s[0]=='$NodeData' ):
            goodline=1


    f.close()
    return displacements              


points, cells, point_data, cell_data, field_data =    meshio.read("Wing.msh")

x=points[:,0]
y=points[:,1]
z=points[:,2]
s=numpy.zeros(z.size)+1

triangles=cells ['triangle']

InputFile='Wing-results.msh'

nodes=ReadGmshNodes(InputFile,3)
displacements=ReadGmshDisplacements(InputFile)




from traits.api import HasTraits, Range, Instance,Enum,Array, \
    on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View, Item, Group,CheckListEditor

from mayavi.core.api import PipelineBase,Source
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, SceneEditor, \
            MlabSceneModel




def applyscalefactor(scalefactor):
    t = displacements[:,2]*scalefactor
    xdisp=x+displacements[:,0]
    ydisp=y+displacements[:,1]
    zdisp=z+t
    return xdisp,ydisp,zdisp

    class MyModel(HasTraits):
    scalefactor = Range(0,100,0,)
    minvalue = Range(-0.00483,0,-0.00483,)
    maxvalue = Range(0,1.58*10**-3,0,)
    coordinates =  Array('d', (3,), labels=['x', 'y', 'z'], cols=3,
                 desc='the coordinate of the picked point')
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())
    plot = Instance(PipelineBase)
    figure = None;
    colorbar = None;
    dispCB = displacements[:,2]
    clickpoint_glyphs = None ;
    glyph_points = None ;
    data_src3d = Instance(Source)
    choose_axis = Enum('X', 'Y', 'Z')

@on_trait_change('minvalue,maxvalue,scene.activated')
def update_colorbar(self):
    if self.colorbar is None:
        self.colorbar =self.scene.mlab.colorbar(title='Wing',orientation='vertical', nb_labels=6)
    else:
        self.colorbar.data_range=[self.minvalue,self.maxvalue]


@on_trait_change('coordinates,scene.activated')           
def picker_callback(self,objPicker):
    print(objPicker)


@on_trait_change('scalefactor,scene.activated')
def update_plot(self):
    x,y,z=applyscalefactor(self.scalefactor)
    if self.plot is None:
        self.figure=self.scene.mlab.gcf()
        self.plot = self.scene.mlab.triangular_mesh(x,y,z,triangles,scalars=self.dispCB,representation='surface')
        self.clickpoint_glyphs = self.scene.mlab.points3d(x,y,z,s,colormap="copper",scale_factor=0.001)
        self.glyph_points =self.clickpoint_glyphs.glyph.glyph_source.glyph_source.output.points.to_array()
        self.figure.on_mouse_pick(self.picker_callback,type='point')



    else:
        self.plot.mlab_source.set(x=x, y=y, z=z,scale_factor=0.001,scalars=self.dispCB)
        self.update_colorbar()


view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                 height=250, width=300, show_label=False),
            Group(
                    '_', 'scalefactor','minvalue','maxvalue'
                 ),

            Group(Item('coordinates'),Item('choose_axis',
                            style='simple',
                            editor=CheckListEditor(values='XYZ')),
                        orientation='vertical'),
            scrollable=True,
            height=100,
            resizable=True,
            )



my_model = MyModel()
my_model.configure_traits()
```

[image: 3D Geometry Python Model]

Comment: As a general comment on your code, please place your import statements at the top of the file (here's a reference as to why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/128577/295246).