# Is this correct to import module only in function, not in a start of file?

Tags: python, import

So, i have a itchy question about `import ModuleName` and where i should to put this operator. In a start of file or in a function?

```
import some_module

def main():
    some_module.SomeStuff()
```

Or:

```
def main():
    import some_module
    some_module.SomeStuff()
```

But if i'll use it in more than one function? Will this correct or *stupid*? Or i need to create class with `__init__` function like this: `self.module = some_module.SomeStuff()`? And then call it in other functions under a class?

Comment: read: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should Python import statements always be at the top of a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-python-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a class for import is not pythonic actually it's bad. You should import module as a name space for calling functions in that module or you can import specific functions:

```
from some_module import SomeFunc1, SomeFunc2
# or
import some_module
some_module.SomeFunc1()
```

Import statement must be at top of the source file(look pep8)

Answer (score 0):

- If you use `some_module` only in `def main():`, you could import it within the function.
- It does not improve the performance in most of the cases as statet in [Should Python import statements always be at the top of a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-python-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module)
- It also breaks the rules of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is `import module` or `from module import func_a` in the start of the file. It will look cleaner and better. If you only want to import one or two functions just use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

[pep08 recommands that all imports should happen at the beginning of the module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), and that's the way to go unless you have a very compelling reason to do otherwise.

The only reason I can think of would be a circular dependency between two modules (module A tries to import module B which tries to import module A etc...), but then it's better to cleanly solve the problem by factoring the common elements in a third module that depends neither on A nor B.