# How to end a while loop when one variable is greater than the other?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I want my while loop to end when the num value is less than the random number.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
num = int(input("Please choose a number (1-10): "))
import random
random = random.randint(1,5)
while (num > random):
    print(num, random)
```

I want it to print (num, random) until the num is less than the random.

Comment: Why do you think that you are doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the body of the while loop is defined indented below the while keyword.
So you most likely want to change one of the two numbers in the while body.

so either

```
while num > random:
    number=int(input("Please choose a number (1-10): "))
```

or

```
while num > random_num:
    random_num=random.randint(1,5)
```

Note that you are overwriting the random package by naming a variable random, which is something you almost never want.

You also should try to import only at the top of a file:
[Should import statements always be at the top of a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module)

edit: full code:

```
import random
random_num=random.randint(1,5)
number=int(input("Please choose a number (1-10): "))
while number > random_num
    print(number ,random_num)
    number=int(input("Please choose a number (1-10): "))
# now the number is <= random_num
```

Comment: but wouldn't it give me an error because the 'num' or 'random_num' is not defined before the while statement?

Comment: yes, you would need to declare them one time above the while loop

Comment: oh ok that makes sense. Thank you!